# Access database Double field value not save correctly

Tags: .net, database, ms-access

We have a program that convert a XML file to an Access database. A couple of months ago, one of your client hit a bug, the values for 2 fields in a table was not the same from the XML file, the value was truncate. To correct the problem, we change those 2 field from Single To Double and everything was fine.

Today, one of your employe use this new version of the program and encounter an other bug. The problem is when the value is save from the XML file, it change. Example: the value from the XML file is 3628.40 and Access save 3628,39990234375 and when we query the value, we obtain 3628,39990234375. Is there a way to have Access store 3628.40 without changing the field type?

I know the problem doesn't come from the program, the SQL Server conversion save the wright value in a Double field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ONLY time you want to use floating point data types is when absolute precision isn't important.  Which is actually pretty rare.

If it is important, as your client pointed out, then you need to use a Decimal or Money type depending on system.

Comment: ps Access does not have a Money data type

Comment: @Brad: in access it's called "Currency" which is the same thing.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the change, but I'll have to rewrite a bit of the app to use the decimal. Thx

Answer (score -1):

I would look at where the data is stored on the table and see what type it is and change it to currency or accounting. Accounting delivers a cleaner appearance and is easier to read, IMHO. You don't mention how you output...an Excel doc? Word report? Export to SharePoint?

Also I would guess that it is the XML file that is truncated when it is imported...Access is just showing the value that was imported. How is the original value stored into the XML file? Has there been any changes on the data input end? Unless someone went in and changed something, I don't think your database is what's wrong.

Start with the user, watch the input process and make sure that is right before messing with your db. Just a thought.